# Is there method similar to 'Find' available when we Loop through folder (of files) using Dir Function in excel vba?

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

As we know, we use **Find()** method to find whether a **string** or any **Microsoft Excel data type** exists in an excel.

(Usually we do it on set of data)

I want to know if any such method available when we loop through folder(of files) using Dir function.

**Situation:**

I have an excel - '**FileNames.xlsx**' in which 'Sheet1' has names of files having extensions `.pdf`/`.jpg`/`.jpeg`/`.xls`/`.xlsx`/`.png.`/`.txt`/`.docx`/ `.rtf` in column A.

I have a folder named '**Folder**' which has most(or all) of the files from 'FileNames.xlsx'.

I have to check whether all the file-names mentioned in the 'FileNames.xlsx' exist in 'Folder'.

For this I have written the below VBScript(.vbs):

```
strMessage =Inputbox("Enter No. of Files in Folder","Input Required")  
set xlinput = createobject("excel.application")
set wb123 =xlinput.workbooks.Open("E:\FileNames.xlsx")

set sh1 =wb123.worksheets("Sheet1")

    For i = 2 to strMessage +1

    namei = sh1.cells(i,1).value

    yesi = "E:\Folder"+ namei +

    If namei <> yesi Then
        sh1.cells(i,1).Interior.Color = vbRed
    Else
    End If
    Next

    msgbox "Success"
xlinput.quit
```

As I wasn't able to get the required Output I tried it recording a small Excel VBA Macro. (Changed FileNames.xlsx to FileNames.xlsm)

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()

    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim filename As Range
    Dim MyFile As String

    MyFolder = "E:\Folder"
    For Each filename In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2A:" & lastRow)

    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xlsx")
    'Here I actually need to pass all file extensions to Dir

    Do While MyFile <> ""
    If filename = MyFile Then
    'Do Nothing
    Else
    filename.Interior.Color = vbRed

    MyFile = Dir

    Next
End Sub
```

The above is a failed attempt.

I thought of trying it with method similar to Find()

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    'Dim LastFile As Long  
    'Is there need of it (LastFile variable)? I kept this variable 
    'to save (prior known) count of files in folder.

    lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    'LastFile = 'Pass count of Files in folder to this variable.

    Dim fileName As Range
    For Each fileName In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & lastRow)

    Dim rngFnder As Range

    On Error Resume Next

    'Error at below line. 
     Set rngFnder = Dir("E:\Folder\").Find(filename)    
    'This line gives me error 'Invalid Qualifier' 
    'I am trying to use method similar to Find()     

        If rngFnder Is Nothing Then
        filename.Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

But, I couldn't achieve the result. Can anyone tell me is there any such function available to 'Find' whether all filenames in an excel exist in a folder after looping through folder using **Dir**?

As per my knowledge, Dir function works with only one file extension at a time.
Is it possible to use Dir function for multiple file extensions at a time?

**Expected Output:**

Assume I have 8 filenames in 'FileNames(.xlsx/.xlsm)'. Out of which **Arabella.pdf** and **Clover.png** are not found in 'Folder', Then I want to color cells for these filenames in red background in excel as in below image.

[image: Dir and Find() with multiple file extensions]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim filename As Range
    Dim MyFile As String

    MyFolder = "E:\Folder"
    For Each filename In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & lastRow)

        MyFile = MyFolder & "\" & filename
        If Not FileExists(MyFile) Then
            filename.Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If

    Next
End Sub

Public Function FileExists(strFullpathName As String) As Boolean

If Dir(strFullpathName) <> "" Then
    FileExists = True
Else
    FileExists = False
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can output a list of the files that are contained in the folder. I found a really helpful tutorial on that here: http://software-solutions-online.com/2014/03/05/list-files-and-folders-in-a-directory/#Jump1

If you then loop through both the original and the output lists and look for a match. Easiest is to first colour them all red, and un-colour the matches. Else you would need an additional if-statement that states: When you reach the last element in the original list, and no match has been found, then colour red.

Edit: For continuity's sake I copied the code bits of the link I mentioned above:

Getting all file names form within 1 folder:

```
Sub  Example1()
Dim  objFSO As  Object
Dim  objFolder As  Object
Dim  objFile As  Object
Dim  i As  Integer 

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject 
Set  objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object 
Set  objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("D:StuffFreelancesWebsiteBlogArraysPics")
i = 1
'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path 
For  Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    'print file name 
    Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name 
    'print file path 
    Cells(i + 1, 2) = objFile.Path 
    i = i + 1 
Next  objFile
End  Sub
```